# Gatling switch protocols during scenario

Tags: gatling

I'm trying to create a Gatling scenario which requires switching the protocol to a different host during the test. The user journey is

```
https://example.com/page1
https://example.com/page2
https://accounts.example.com/signin
https://example.com/page3
```

so as part of a single scenario, I need to ether switch the `protocol` defined in the scenario set up, or switch the `baseUrl` defined on the protocol but I can't figure out how to do that.

A basic scenario might look like

```scala
package protocolexample

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class Example extends Simulation {
  val exampleHttp = http.baseURL("https://example.com/")
  val exampleAccountsHttp = http.baseURL("https://accounts.example.com/")

  val scn = scenario("Signin")
    .exec(
      http("Page 1").get("/page1")
    )
    .exec(
      http("Page 2").get("/page2")
    )
    .exec(
      // This needs to be done against accounts.example.com
      http("Signin").get("/signin")
    )
    .exec(
      // Back to example.com
      http("Page 3").get("/page3")
    )

  setUp(
    scn.inject(
      atOnceUsers(3)
    ).protocols(exampleHttp)
  )
}
```

I just need to figure out how to ether switch the host or protocol for the 3rd step. I know I can create multiple scenarios but this needs to be a single user flow across multiple hosts.

I've tried directly using the other protocol

```scala
exec(
  // This needs to be done against accounts.example.com
  exampleAccountsHttp("Signin").get("/signin")
)
```

which results in

```
protocolexample/example.scala:19: type mismatch;
 found   : String("Signin")
 required: io.gatling.core.session.Session
       exampleAccountsHttp("Signin").get("/signin")
```

and also changing the base URL on the request

```scala
exec(
  // This needs to be done against accounts.example.com
  http("Signin").baseUrl("https://accounts.example.com/").get("/signin")
)
```

which results in

```
protocolexample/example.scala:19: value baseUrl is not a member of io.gatling.http.request.builder.Http
```

Comment: @Meiko Hi, yes sorry for the delay. Marked as accepted

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use an absolute URI (inclusive protocol) as a parameter for `Http.get`, `Http.post` and so on.

```scala
class Example extends Simulation {
  val exampleHttp = http.baseURL("https://example.com/")
  val scn = scenario("Signin")
    .exec(http("Page 1").get("/page1"))
    .exec(http("Page 2").get("/page2"))
    .exec(http("Signin").get("https://accounts.example.com/signin"))
    .exec(http("Page 3").get("/page3"))
  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(3))
    .protocols(exampleHttp))
}
```

see: https://gatling.io/docs/current/cheat-sheet/#http-protocol-urls-baseUrl

> **baseURL:** Sets the base URL of all **relative URLs** of the scenario on which the configuration is applied.

Comment: But this doesn't answer a question "how to switch protocols during scenario?". What if want to delete default protocol headers for particular requests? Or add more headers to the protocol after a certain request?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working in **gatling**.

### SOLUTION:

### => WHAT WE USE IF WE HAVE ONE HTTPBASE:

```
var httpConf1= http.baseUrl("https://s1.com")
```

### =>FOR MULTIPLE HTTPBASE:

```
var httpConf1=http.**baseUrls**("https://s1.com","https://s2.com","https://s3.com")
```

You can use baseUrls function which takes a list of httpBase urls.

### ANOTHER METHOD:

Reading from csv file all httpbase and storing it in list buffer in scala language and then converting it into list while passing it in http.baseUrls

```
var listOfTenants:ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String] //buffer 
var httpConf1=http.**baseUrls**(listOfTenants.toList) //converting buffer to list.
```

Hope it helps!.
Thank you.